# How to set a node zone in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, cluster-computing

According to [CouchDB doc](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/cluster/databases.html), in order to put a node in a zone (similarly to BigCouch), we need to modify `_nodes` database, adding a field like `"zone": "metro-dc-a"`, using the `http://127.0.0.1:5986/_nodes` endpoint, if I understood well. I didn't find any hint on how to modify an existing database attributes. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Should be the same as modifying any document in CouchDB, with a PUT, right?

Comment: As reported in the [doc](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/common.html#put--db), PUT verb is used to create a new database. POST is used to add a new document to it instead.

Comment: PUT is also used to add new documents, and to update existing documents, [as documented](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/document/common.html#put--db-docid).

Comment: Yes, *documents*, not *DBs*...

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Probably I misunderstood the [CouchDB zone documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/cluster/databases.html). I have to update every `node` document inside the `_nodes` database, so I can use PUT on every document, adding the `"zone":"value"` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Each node must be labeled with a `zone` attribute and update the node’s document in `:5986/_nodes` database, add a key-value pair of the form:

> "zone": "{zone-name}"

First, Get the node information from Cluster membership.

```
$ curl -s -X GET "http://localhost:5984/_membership" --user <admin-user>
```

Get node’s document from Cluster.

```
$ curl -X GET http://localhost:5986/_nodes/couchdb@192.168.1.10 --user <admin-user>
```

Define zone (Ex:`metro-dc-a`) of all of the nodes in your cluster.

```
$ curl -X PUT http://localhost:5986/_nodes/couchdb@192.168.1.10 --user <admin-user> -d '{
  "_id": "couchdb@192.168.1.10",
  "_rev": "1-967a00dff5e02add41819138abb3284d",
  "zone": "metro-dc-a"
}'
```

Finally, In the local.ini config of each node, define a consistent cluster-wide setting like:

> [cluster] placement = :2,:1

CouchDB will ensure that two replicas for a shard will be hosted on nodes with the zone attribute set to `metro-dc-a` and one replica will be hosted on a new with the zone attribute set to `metro-dc-b`.

https://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.3.1/cluster/sharding.html#specifying-database-placement